# Getting a value from a Node.js callback

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm trying to get my head around callbacks in Node.JS and it's pretty foreign compared to what I'm used to.

I have the following example from another post on here:

```
var someOutput;

var myCallback = function(data) {
  console.log('got data: '+data);
  someOutput = data;
};


    var usingItNow = function(callback) {
  callback('get it?');
};

//now do something with someOutput outside of the functions
```

I have added the someOutput variable - I want to get the text 'get it?' (obviously I don't) into there so that I can concatenate it on to a string, but it's not working in any combination I've tried.

I must be missing something fundamental here!

Thank you for the help.

Comment: call `usingItNow(myCallback);`

Comment: Haha, thank you.  It seems like a pretty stupid question now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the function:

```
usingItNow(myCallback);
```

But anyway it is not a good practice to use callback to set variable and consume later. It will work for you now, but later if callback will be async, it will fail.

Consider using `Promise` and use `someOutput` in the `then` function.
A good Promise package is [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com)

If you want to do it like a pro, consider using `Promise.coroutine` 
http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html

Or `async` + `await` if you are using an updated version of Node.js

Look on http://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions to check what avilable on your node version

Comment: I feel like that might have just happened - I'm trying to call a web service inside the function and someOutput is coming back undefined - I'll try your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly the case. I'll some more explanation in my answer

Answer (score 0):

As commented by emil:

"call usingItNow(myCallback);"

doh!